# I'm thinking about buying a new car

Tags: prepositions

> I'm thinking about buying a new car. 
>   I'm thinking of buying a new car.

Do we use "about" or ‘of" in sentences above?

Comment: Either one is acceptable.  I would always use *about* but other people I know would always use *of*.  Use what suits you best.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/think-of-versus-think-about