# Usage of tenses

Tags: prepositions, tense

Is the following sentence correct:

> *I know you were thinking of me when I would be getting married.*

To put it in context to make the intended meaning more obvious:

John and Mike; close friends. A month ago, they were sitting and talking. Mike kept silent. John said to Mike:
"I know you were thinking of me when I would be getting married" (the moment John would be joyfully experiencing when he is getting married).

Comment: The sentence sounds  OK grammatically.

Comment: It doesn't sound very good to me.  (I can come up with a parse in my head that works, but it takes some work.)

Comment: Yes, please. I would love to see your suggestions. I really appreciate that.

Comment: This is really confusing because "I know you **were**" implies that the wedding has already occurred... but "**would be** getting married" implies that it has not yet occurred.

Comment: If John has already gotten married, then say: John said to Mike: "I know you were thinking of me when I got married" or "I know you were thinking of me when I was getting married." This is an example of KISS, or "Keep it simple, stupid," which is a [common expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) meaning *most systems work best if they are kept simple rather than made complicated* and by which I am not really calling you 'stupid'.

Answer (score 1):

> I know you were thinking of me when I would be getting married.

The reason this is wrong, is because the tenses are all mixed up. The sentence states that the speaker knows that the recipient of the speech was thinking of him when he got married, but the speaker hasn't been married yet (at least, I think that's what the sentence is implying.)

On the other hand, if the sentence is saying that Mike was thinking of John during the period between his proposal (and it's acceptance) and his wedding, then the sentence is still really confusing. Even if something is *technically* right, don't use it if it sounds wrong or is confusing. Instead, try:

> I know you were thinking of me when **I was going to get married.**
>
> I know you were thinking of me when **I were to be married.** (cryptic)

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

On a second (or tenth) reading, I think I get what you're trying to say.

#### "About" vs "Of"

"Thinking of" and "thinking about" can [sometimes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/think-of-versus-think-about) be interchangeable but sometimes one is preferred over the other:

> If I had to summarize, I'd say that think of seems to mean recalling something specific, while think about seems to mean considering some subject in a more vague or general way for some length of time. The two are sometimes interchangeable because there are many situations where you can't think about something without also thinking of it, such as when you are fondly remembering your deceased mother.

As an AmE speaker, I think your phrasing would be better served by using "about" instead of "of". I'm not sure if other English speakers would concur.

> I know you were thinking **about** me when I would be getting married.

"Thinking of" me seems wrong because you really mean [about](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about), definition 2.

> used to indicate the object of a thought, feeling, or action

#### Emphasize the thought

You need some way to emphasize that "when I would be getting married" is what he was thinking about... right now it is really ambiguous.

One way you can do this is by adding the word "and".

> I know you were thinking **about** me **and** when I would be getting married.

You could also use other words like "specifically"

> I know you were thinking about me, specifically when I would/will be getting married.

or get rid of the "me":

> I know you were thinking about when I [would/will] get married.

Though this still sounds a bit odd.

#### Simplify

To be honest, I think that you're over complicating what you're trying to say... simplify the sentence by getting rid of extra verbs:

> I know you were thinking about my future wedding/marriage.

You can also make it more descriptive by changing "thinking" to "imagining" or "fantasizing", though "imagining" doesn't need the "about".

> I know you were imagining my future wedding/marriage.

#### Final Thoughts

These all mean pretty much the same thing and I **think** they mean what you're trying to say. If I had to make a choice, I'd recommend the ultra-simplified version:

> I know you were thinking about my future wedding/marriage.

Or the "and" version, but contracted:

> I know you were thinking about me **and** when I'd be getting married.

Comment: Thank you so much for illuminating me with your informative thoughts. As someone above mentioned that it sounds better to use "About" instead of "Of". The sentence attempts to describe how John realized that Mike was thinking about John when John would assumingly be getting married. But in the reality, John refuses to get married.

Comment: @Johnny Honestly that doesn't matter in this sentence. You would need to add more to the sentence, like "... but it's never going to happen."